# sql query help multi joins?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

here are my tables, im using sql developer oracle

Carowner(Carowner  id,  carowner-name,)

Car (Carid,  car-name, carowner-id*)

Driver(driver_licenceno, driver-name)

Race(Race no,  race-name,  prize-money,  race-date)

RaceEntry(Race no*,  Car id*,  Driver_licenceno*,  finishing_position)

im trying to list to do the query below

**which drivers have  come  second  in  races  from  the  start  of  this  year.
lncluding  race  name,  driver  name,  and  the name of the car  in  the  output**

i have attempted

```
select r.racename, d.driver-name, c.carowner-name

from race r, driver d, car c, raceentry re

where re.finishing_position = 2 and r.race-date is ...
```

Comment: You need to learn proper join syntax.  Could you at least rewrite your query with `join`s rather than `,`s in the `from` clause?

Comment: i dont know how to join multiple tables (more than 2)

Comment: Are you sure that there are hyphens in the column names and not underscores? Ie driver_name vs driver-name

Comment: im not too bothered about that, i just need a general idea of how to produce the query. naming conventions can be a rough estimate

Comment: Sentences begin with capital letters and end with periods. The string "i" is not a word in the English language.

Comment: IMplict joins are a SQL antipattern and shoud NEVER be used. Looks to me as if you have a cross join.

Answer (score 0):

First off, multiple joins in the where clause are hard to get used to when you define more than 3 or 4 tables IMHO.

Do this instead:

```
Select 
  a.columnfroma
, b.columnfromb
, c.columnfromc
from tablea a
  join tableb b on a.columnAandBShare = b.columnAandBShare
  join tablec c on b.columnBandCShare = c.columnBandCShare
```

This while no one would say is a method you have to use, it is a much more readable method of performing joins.

Otherwise you are doing the joins in the where clause and if you have other predicates with your joins you are going to have to comment out which is which if you ever need to go back and look at it.

Comment: so am i correct in that i have to join 4 tables? like ive defined in my "from"

Comment: you have joined 4 tables but not correctly. In part becasue you are using implicit joins which is an extremely poor programming practice.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
select r.racename, d.driver-name, c.carowner-name
from race r
join raceentry re on r.race_no = re.race_no
join car c on re.car_Id = c.car_id
join driver d on re.driverliscenceNo = d.driverliscenceNo
where re.finishing_position = 2 and r.race-date >='20130101'
```

This assumes only one car and one driver with a finsih place of 2nd in a particular race. You may need more conditions otherwise.  If this is your own table design, you need to start right now learning to be consistent in your nameing between tables. It is important. Fields that are in multiple tables should have the same name and data type.  Also you need to stop using implicit syntax. This ia aSQL antipattern and a very poor programming technique. It leads to mistakes such as accidental cross joins and is harder to read and maintain when things get more complex.  As you are clearly learning, you need to stop this bad habit right now.